# How to get setInterval to execute exactly every n milliseconds?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a piece of code to execute exactly every second. I am finding, however, that there is a >1000ms time difference between each run of the setInterval.

```
var incrementUnitCount = function() {

    var now = new Date();

    console.log('Shift' + now + 'ms' + now.getMilliseconds());

};

setInterval(incrementUnitCount2, interval);
```

The output looks like this:

```
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:05 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms457
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms458
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:07 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms460
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms463
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms465
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:10 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms468
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:11 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms468
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms470
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:13 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms472
```

As shown, the difference in time between each call is 1001ms, not 1000. If I have a time-sensitive application, how can I guarantee a call every 1000 ms - something like this:

```
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms470
js/schedule.js (148) :ShiftTue Mar 28 2017 21:44:13 GMT-0400 (EDT)ms470
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can’t. What is the application? Do you actually need an exact interval, or just one that doesn’t drift?

Comment: You can not.  Most modern user-oriented operating systems are not capable of that precision of scheduling.

Comment: Hmm,  I guess I don't understand the difference? I think I don't need one that drifts? I have an accumulator to measure total time duration that will be off after the drift goes into the next second.

Comment: You can't get exactly the interval you request every time, but if you use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` then you can adjust the requested delay each time to account for any drift in the previous timeout, thus keeping things on track overall.

Comment: So you’re doing something like `seconds++;` in the timer callback and hoping to get an accurate number of seconds afterwards? If so, instead store `performance.now()` when the timer starts and subtract it from `performance.now()` in the future to get milliseconds difference. If not, could you explain in more detail what/how you’re measuring, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you may be able to make a more accurate (not exact) replacement setInterval using requestAnimationFrame.  From https://gist.github.com/joelambert/1002116

```
window.requestInterval = function(fn, delay) {
    if( !window.requestAnimationFrame       && 
        !window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && 
        !(window.mozRequestAnimationFrame && window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame) && // Firefox 5 ships without cancel support
        !window.oRequestAnimationFrame      && 
        !window.msRequestAnimationFrame)
            return window.setInterval(fn, delay);

    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        handle = new Object();

    function loop() {
        var current = new Date().getTime(),
            delta = current - start;

        if(delta >= delay) {
            fn.call();
            start = new Date().getTime();
        }

        handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
    };

    handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
    return handle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pre-computing an array of DateTime values and I just check the current time against the array to keep track of time.

Thanks!